# Which are the ways of discovering?

Tags: catan-explorers-pirates

Can an undiscovered hex be discovered only by a ship or can it be discovered in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [rules](https://www.catan.com/download/6682/catan-explorers-pirates-rules-3-4-players):

> **Discovering with Ships**
>
> To discover new land, you must move one of your ships towards the unexplored areas of the board (example 3 A).
>
> If, after moving a ship, one of its ends (bow or stern) points toward the corner (intersection) of an undiscovered hex, you muist discover that hex (example 3 B).
>
> Turn the hex over. If it is a terrain hex, take a number token from the stack whose color/icon matches the color/icon on the back of the terrain hex and place it, number side face up on the hex (example 3 C).

So this implies that this is the only way to diecover new hexes. The shape of the unexplored island is such, that each hex is reachable by sea, there is even a weird "hole" to enable access to the center hex. So I think this is the way the game should be played.

Comment: It is a bit ambiguous b/c "To discover new land, you must move one of your ships towards the unexplored areas" is under "Discovering with Ships", so it only makes sense that you have to move the ship.
If that first sentence was under "Discovering", I wouldn't have had any doubt, so I'm still not convinced.

Comment: @Saran, I am certain, that, if there was another way, there was at least some kind of hint in the rules. But there is none. Games like catan normally have rules without big omissions.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe, The rules do specify that ships are the only way to discover.  The bottom of page 5 says, "If you build a road in such a way that one of its ends points toward an undiscovered hex, you can't discover that hex.  You can only dsicover hexes by means of ships."